# Is there a way to reverse the ratio test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My question arises from the following problem: Let $ a_n $ be a real series, so that $ \sum_{n=1}^ \infty a_n $ converges and $a_n \ge 0 $ and $a_n$ monotonously decreasing.

It is to prove: $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} na_n = 0 $

There are probably several ways to prove this, but I wondered, if there was also a way to use certain properties of a series and the sequence to reverse the ratio test and if there is also some sort of minimalist property to allow such a reversal.

First: The ratio test states: A series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ converges, if $ \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} {| {a_{n+1} \over a_n} | } \lt 1 $ .

I see the problem, that the ratio of $ {|{ a_{n+1} \over a_n }|} $ does not have to be well defined. But I think that problem can be circumvented, by using the property, that every convergent series has a convergent sub sequence. Now there can infinity many equal elements zero, however this would turn the above given question trivial. But I think even if one doesn't have the property of the monotonously decreasing sequence, one would have to able to find a sub sequence on which the ratio test is applicable / well defined as long as all sub sequences of the main sequence tend to 0, that should be also true for complex series. 
I am not entirely sure, if I didn't make an error some where, thus I would be happy, if someone could verify my thoughts or give an counterexample or add something in general to my request.

Comment: Your statement of the ratio test is wrong. For instance, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ converges according to your version of the test.

Comment: That is not *quite* the ratio test. You need that there exists $r<1$ and $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|\leq r$ for all $n\geq N_0$. Note the subtle difference; by your statement, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ converges. As for the actual question, it may be possible to prove it in this way but such a method does not seem obvious to me, and would not be how I would approach the problem.

Comment: Maybe I missing some point but ı think that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{1/n}=0$ is valid since $\sum a_n$ is convergent and $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent series with nonnegative terms.

Comment: ah yes, I fixed the ratio test

Comment: If $a_n$ is montonely decreasing and $a_n \geq 0$ then if $a_N = 0$ then $a_n = 0$ for all $n\geq N$ so $\sum^\infty a_n = \sum^N a_n$ and the problem becomes trivial.

Comment: I would prove that if $\limsup n.a_n>0$, then the series does not converge.

Comment: That's not the ratio test either, Imago! The limit doesn't have to exist for the test to be valid. If you say "lim sup" instead of "lim", now _that's_ the ratio test.

Comment: idd, "sup" is necessary for the test to work. I am surprised and shocked at myself how much I seem to take for granted.. or how much half knowledge I have.

Comment: "sup" is not necessary for the test to work; it just lets you show convergence for a wider class of series. The version you gave is still correct, but weaker than the genuine ratio test.

Comment: However I don't see a reason, why one should not work with the lim sup version first. I will view this as a nice lesson and also the chance to revise my scripts etc. and check how small changes in the formulas, definitions or postulates affect them. At the moment I am just trying to get a better knowledge, theoretical understanding of those matters, since I actually lack time to do exercises. But thank you a lot for your patience.